# Having trouble writing data to a file using fs (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, fs

I'm trying to set a variable in a seperate json file to false/true depending on it's state, and am getting an error while attempting to do so.

Here are the variables used:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const maintenancefile = require("../util/maintenance.json");
let state = maintenancefile.maintenancestatus;
JSON.stringify(state);
let changetofalse = "{\n\"maintenancestatus\": \"false\"\n}"
JSON.stringify(changetofalse);
let changetotrue = "{\n\"maintenancestatus\": \"true\"\n}"
JSON.stringify(changetotrue);
```

And here's the process of me trying to write to the file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'maintenance',
    description: "PUTS BOT IN MAINTENANCE MODE - BOT ADMINISTRATOR ONLY",
    execute(message, args){
       if(message.member.user.id != '294773357864550401') return;
       if(state = "false") {
           fs.writeFile(maintenancefile, changetotrue, (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
          });
           return message.channel.send("BOT PUT IN MAINTENANCE MODE - REQUESTED BY " + message.member.user.tag + " (" + message.member.user.tag + ").")

       }
       if(state = "true") {
           fs.writeFile(maintenancefile, changetofalse, (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
          });
           return message.channel.send("BOT TAKEN OUT OF MAINTENANCE MODE - REQUESTED BY " + message.member.user.tag + " (" + message.member.user.tag + ").")
       }
       return;
       // WIP
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'maintenance',
    description: 'PUTS BOT IN MAINTENANCE MODE - BOT ADMINISTRATOR ONLY'
}
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object
    at Object.open (fs.js:409:3)
    at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1168:6)
    at Object.execute (/Users/name/Downloads/litemoderation-master/commands/maintenance.js:18:15)
    at Client.bot.on.message (/Users/name/Downloads/litemoderation-master/index.js:150:40)
    at Client.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/Users/name/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/Users/name/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is completely unclear what you're trying to accomplish with this code and there are numerous things wrong in it.  As Jacob has outlined, the error is because you're calling `fs.writeFile()` without passing a path as the first argument.  But, with no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish with this code, we can't really say more than that.  Also, the  `changeToTrue` and `changeToFalse` variables make absolutely no sense at all.  You're calling `JSON.stringify()` on something that is basically already JSON.  No point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to break down the error you're getting. You'll notice that it's when you call `writeFile`. If you look at the [`writeFile` docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), the first argument is supposed to be a file path. You're passing `maintenancefile` for that, which is defined as:

```
const maintenancefile = require("../util/maintenance.json");
```

This is why it's saying that the `path` parameter isn't the string it's expecting (the file path) but somethinng else.

If your intent was to overwrite that file, not to parse the JSON, then you can use `require.resolve('../util/maintenance.json')`, which will give you the file path instead of the parsed contents of the file.